# What is the name of the reveal-menu-bar-on-Alt interaction?

Tags: menu, desktop-application, keyboard-shortcuts, names

Firefox has the following interaction on the GNOME desktop (observed in Firefox ~55, GNOME ~3.26):

- Starts with menu bar hidden
- When you click <kbd>Alt</kbd> the menu bar appears [1] (and stays visible after the key is released)
- When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> again, the menu bar is hidden

Does this interaction have a name?

[1]: For example, when starting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combo to open the "File" menu.

Comment: I'm on 56 and doesn't happen for me. It's just `Alt` or did you forget another key?

Comment: @Devin I'm on GNOME (GNU/Linux) so it might be specific to that platform, I've updated the question accordingly -- or it could be an option I enabled, I'll check and update if that's the case

Comment: This happens in Windows, too. Or it used to, and I loved it. Working on Macs, this is the thing I miss the most about Windows, as it provided a visual, immediate way to find shortcuts, that activated along the way, and was learnable, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this a keyboard shortcut for [progressive disclosure](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/). Progressive disclosure is when you hide stuff that your user doesn't need for basic tasks. Think of Advanced Options in any application. There's a link or button (in this case the [alt] key) to open/reveal the disclosed options.

There's also staged disclosure which is commonly referred to as a Wizard. That's where the next options or tasks are disclosed in stages or in a queue.